# Setting Up VkRenderPassBeginInfo.pClearValues Pointer Array with Project Panama (JEP 434)

Tags: java, vulkan, project-panama

I am trying to create a pointer to an array of of two (2) [VkClearValues](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkClearValue.html) using Java's Project Panama (JEP 434, JDK 20). One clear value is for the color attachment, one is for the depth buffer.

My attempt at that is the following:

```java
var pClearValue = VkClearValue.allocate(arena);
VkClearValue.color$slice(pClearValue).setAtIndex(C_FLOAT, 0, 0.0f);
VkClearValue.color$slice(pClearValue).setAtIndex(C_FLOAT, 1, 1.0f);
VkClearValue.color$slice(pClearValue).setAtIndex(C_FLOAT, 2, 0.0f);
VkClearValue.color$slice(pClearValue).setAtIndex(C_FLOAT, 3, 0.0f);

var pDepthClearValue = VkClearValue.allocate(arena);
VkClearDepthStencilValue.depth$set(VkClearValue.depthStencil$slice(pDepthClearValue), 1f);
VkClearDepthStencilValue.stencil$set(VkClearValue.depthStencil$slice(pDepthClearValue), 0);

var pClearValues = arena.allocateArray(VkClearValue.$LAYOUT(), 2);
pClearValues.setAtIndex(C_POINTER, 0, pClearValue.get(C_POINTER, 0));
pClearValues.setAtIndex(C_POINTER, 1, pDepthClearValue.get(C_POINTER, 0));

VkRenderPassBeginInfo.pClearValues$set(pRenderPassBeginInfo, 0, pClearValues);
```

Using Renderdoc I see garbage clear values being sent to Vulkan.

If I just try and pass in the one color clear value:

VkRenderPassBeginInfo.pClearValues$set(pRenderPassBeginInfo, 0, pClearValue);

The data is sent correctly (but with no depth clear value (only color)).

I have tried many permutations to try and set up this Pointer array, but I can never succeed in sending two valid depth adjustments.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are off by a level of indirection. The [`VkRenderPassBeginInfo`](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkRenderPassBeginInfo.html) struct has the field `const VkClearValue* pClearValues`, which is an array of structs. But, you seem to be trying to pass an array of pointers to it.

Furthermore, you are reading a pointer from both `pClearValue` and `pDepthClearValue`, which is incorrect since the struct doesn't contain pointers.

It works when passing just a single pointer to a `VkClearValue`, since that can also act as a pointer to an array of a single struct.

If you want to initialize the array correctly, you need to either copy your pre-allocated structs into the array:

```
var pClearValue = VkClearValue.allocate(arena);
...
var pDepthClearValue = VkClearValue.allocate(arena);
...

// VkClearValue* pClearValues = malloc(sizeof(VkClearValue) * 2);
var pClearValues = arena.allocateArray(VkClearValue.$LAYOUT(), 2);
// like doing: '&pClearValues[i]' in C
IntFunction<MemorySegment> slicer =
    i -> pClearValues.asSlice(i * VkClearValue.sizeof(), VkClearValue.sizeof());

// *(&pClearValues[0]) = *pClearValue;
slicer.apply(0).copyFrom(pClearValue);
// *(&pClearValues[1]) = *pDepthClearValue;
slicer.apply(1).copyFrom(pDepthClearValue);

VkRenderPassBeginInfo.pClearValues$set(pRenderPassBeginInfo, 0, pClearValues);
```

Or allocate the array upfront and initialize it's contents directly (this is what I would recommend):

```
// VkClearValue* pClearValues = malloc(sizeof(VkClearValue) * 2);
var pClearValues = arena.allocateArray(VkClearValue.$LAYOUT(), 2);
// like doing: '&pClearValues[i]' in C
IntFunction<MemorySegment> slicer =
    i -> pClearValues.asSlice(i * VkClearValue.sizeof(), VkClearValue.sizeof());

// VkClearValue* pClearValue = &pClearValues[0];
var pClearValue = slicer.apply(0); // reference to the first VkClearValue in the array
VkClearValue.color$slice(pClearValue).setAtIndex(C_FLOAT, 0, 0.0f);
VkClearValue.color$slice(pClearValue).setAtIndex(C_FLOAT, 1, 1.0f);
VkClearValue.color$slice(pClearValue).setAtIndex(C_FLOAT, 2, 0.0f);
VkClearValue.color$slice(pClearValue).setAtIndex(C_FLOAT, 3, 0.0f);

// VkClearValue* pDepthClearValue = &pClearValues[1];
var pDepthClearValue = slicer.apply(1); // reference to the second VkClearValue in the array
VkClearDepthStencilValue.depth$set(VkClearValue.depthStencil$slice(pDepthClearValue), 1f);
VkClearDepthStencilValue.stencil$set(VkClearValue.depthStencil$slice(pDepthClearValue), 0);

VkRenderPassBeginInfo.pClearValues$set(pRenderPassBeginInfo, 0, pClearValues);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jorn!